# catch22: java pattern matcher regex, halt on '(' character

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

The data looks like this:

```
#######################," ]：道寸(daocun)
```

On [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/bY9dP9/1) it seems that the following command would match `道寸` which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
#################,\" ]：(.*?)\(
```

But java says `\(` that the backslash there is an illegal escape character. 
And it throws an 'unclosed group' error if I don't include the backslash.

The ideal output I want it simply `道寸`, how to get it under these circumstances?

Comment: that's strange, because it seems you can escape quotes with only one backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you need to escape the backslash one more time except for backslash present before double quotes.

```
"#################,\" ]：(.*?)\\("
```

Comment: that's strange, because it seems you can escape quotes with only one backslash